# Compute recursion for one column conditionally on values in another columns

Tags: c, recursion, multidimensional-array

I was given dataset named `Temp.dat` with 2 columns ([Dataset here)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_h99E0LRCDBcWz60gQNkBGPgaC_qCclB). I initially formed structure named `structure data_t data[100]` so that I could arrange the columns in an increasing order based on the first column (Column 0 = min(failure time, censored time), Column 1 indicates `1` = Death observation, `0` = censored observation). A portion of the structured dataset has the following form

```
0.064295 1 
0.070548 1 
0.070850 1 
0.071508 0 
0.077981 1 
0.086628 1 
0.088239 1 
0.090754 1 
0.093260 0 
0.094090 1 
0.094367 1 
0.097019 1 
0.099336 1 
0.103765 1 
0.103961 1 
0.111674 0 
0.122609 0 
0.123730 1
```

Now, I want to write the C code to form different time periods whose endpoints always end with entry `1`in the 2nd column. Looks like the following:

**Expected output - 3rd column (Time Interval) added**

```
0.064295 1 [0 0.064295)        
0.070548 1 [0.064295 0.070548) 
0.070850 1 [0.070548 0.070850) 
0.071508 0 [0.070850 0.077891) ---> Skip 0.071508 here because of 0 in column 1 
0.077981 1 [0.070850 0.077981)
0.086628 1 [0.077981 0.086628) 
0.088239 1 [0.086628 0.088239) 
0.090754 1 [0.088239 0.090754) 
0.093260 0 [0.090754 0.094090) 
0.094090 1 [0.090754 0.094090) 
0.094367 1 [0.094090 0.094367) 
0.097019 1 [0.094367 0.097019) 
0.099336 1 [0.097019 0.099336) 
0.103765 1 [0.099336 0.103765) 
0.103961 1 [0.103765 0.103961) 
0.111674 0 [0.103961 0.123730) 
0.122609 0 [0.103961 0.123730) 
0.123730 1 [0.103961 0.123730)
```

So far, I am unable to write the code to perform this. So if anyone could help on this step, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Next, I wrote up the following code to get the output shown below. Note that column 2 is not what I want, but this is the **best** thing so far I could get.

```
  double array[8][MAX];
  double total = 100;
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) { 
    double start = 0;
    double count = 0;
    if(i) start = data[i - 1].x; 
    array[0][i] = data[i].x; 
    array[1][i] = data[i].y; 
    array[2][i] = start; 
    array[3][i] = data[i].x;
    array[4][0] = count;
    array[5][0] = count;
    array[6][0] = total;
    array[7][0] = 1;
    /*keep track of number of deaths and censors at each time t_i*/
    if (fmod(arr[1][i], 2.0) == 1)
      {arr[4][i+1]  = count + 1.0;
       arr[5][i+1]  = count;
      }
    else {arr[4][i+1] = count;
          arr[5][i+1] = count + 1.0;
         }

  return(0);
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
0.064295 1 [0.060493 0.064295) 1.000000 0.000000 191.000000 0.950000
0.070548 1 [0.064295 0.070548) 1.000000 0.000000 190.000000 0.945000
0.070850 1 [0.070548 0.070850) 1.000000 0.000000 189.000000 0.940000
0.071508 0 [0.070850 0.071508) 1.000000 0.000000 188.000000 0.940000
0.077981 1 [0.071508 0.077981) 0.000000 1.000000 187.000000 0.935000
0.086628 1 [0.077981 0.086628) 1.000000 0.000000 186.000000 0.929973
0.088239 1 [0.086628 0.088239) 1.000000 0.000000 185.000000 0.924946
0.090754 1 [0.088239 0.090754) 1.000000 0.000000 184.000000 0.919919
0.093260 0 [0.090754 0.093260) 1.000000 0.000000 183.000000 0.919919
```

Column 7 stands for KM estimator of survival distribution function. It was computed based on the following rules:
 1. If the i-th entry in column 1 is 0, simply save the corresponding i-th entry in column 6 equal to the previous (i-1)th- entry in the same column.
 2. If the i-th entry in column 1 is 1 but one or multiple successive entries before it is 0 (for example, the last entry of column 1 is followed right before by two 0s), we compute the corresponding **i-th** entry in column 6 with the formula: (i-1)-th entry*(1- 1/(j-th entry in column 5)) where the j-th entry in column 5 corresponds to the *nearest* entry 1 in column 1 (for example, the last 4 rows of column 1 has `1 0 0 1` in it, which implies the last entry in column 6 would be computed as `0.890096*(1-1/177)` where `177 =` the first entry in column 5 which has the corresponding entry in column 1 `=` 1 (rather than 0).

**Task left to finish:** First, I need to form the **right** column 2 so that for **a random input** t in the range of column 0, the code would give the corresponding result in column 6.

Second, I want to compute the variance of KM estimator, using this formula:  S(t)^2*(summation over t_i <= t) d_i/(r_i*(r_i-d_i)),

where S(t) = the KM estimator computed at time t (column 7 above), d_i is the total number of deaths up to index i (so, sum of entries up to d_i of column 5 above), r_i = i-th entry in column 6. For example, if t = 0.071, then t_i only has 3 possible values based on Column 0 (t_i would be 0.064295, 0.070548 and 0.070850). I came up with the following working code (not sure if the output was the correct ones)

```
  N = [an integer]; #define size of array here
  double sigma[N];
  sigma[0] = 0;
  double sum[N];
  sum[0] = 0;
  for(int i=1; i< N; i++){
     sum[i] = sum[i-1] + (float)(arr[4][i]/(arr[6][i-1]*(arr[6][i])));
     sigma[i] = pow(arr[7][i],2)*sum[i];
     printf("%.0lf", sigma[i]);
  }
```

**Sample Output**

```
0.004775
0.004750
0.004725
0.004700
0.004675
0.004700
0.004650
0.004625
0.004600
0.004575
0.004600
0.004550
0.004525
0.004500
0.004475
0.004450
0.004425
0.004450
0.004450
0.004400
0.004375
0.004350
0.004325
0.004300
0.004275
0.004250
0.004225
0.004200
0.004175
0.004149
0.004124
0.004150
0.004099
0.004074
0.004100
0.004049
0.004024
0.004051
0.003999
0.003974
0.004001
0.003949
0.003976
0.003923
0.003898
0.003926
0.003873
0.003848
0.003823
0.003797
0.003772
0.003747
0.003775
0.003722
0.003750
0.003696
0.003725
0.003671
0.003700
0.003646
0.003676
0.003621
0.003595
0.003570
0.003544
0.003519
0.003549
0.003494
```

Comment: It's a 2d array.

Comment: No a whole lot of C code here, so why is this tagged C?

Comment: @tadman: I am sorry, but I would like to perform the tasks above in C. Could you help please?

Comment: @coderredoc: I corrected it. Could you give some help on either questions?

Comment: Yeah, and I want a pony. You need to *try something* and show us what you've tried.

Comment: @tadman: I added my attempt for Question 1 so far. I am still stumbled on Question 2. Hope you could help me on this.

Comment: Alright, finally we've got some code here.

Comment: You should redo this question. Show the content of input file, expected output, and MCVE (which we did in the other question) Other people should be able to copy/paste the code and compile.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It would be very long to post the entire thing. The original dataset only contains the first two columns, but not in that order (you helped me sort it yesterday!!). The code includes the steps that generate columns 2-6. I already showed the expected output for question 2. Could you please give it a try?

Comment: Code does not compile.  A [MCVE] gains up-votes.  Your choice.

Comment: I can't make heads and tail out of this. In another post you mentioned Kaplan–Meier formula, which is fairly simple. But I don't know what any of the columns are, I don't know why the data had to be sorted, the mathematical formula you are using is not clear. The sixth column is just zeros and ones, it's the opposite of 2nd column. Why does it have to be calculated recursively? Other people might be familiar this problem if there was MCVE.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: how do you compute the Kaplan-Meier estimator without sorting based on failure/censored time first?? As you asked, I made an extensive post on the questions I am in need of solving, together with the dataset. Hope this makes sense now.

Comment: @chux: I hope this helps now?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I need to form the correct time interval for column 2 (you did *not* mind reading all of the info I posted? That's pretty sad;p)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Write a C code to get the 3rd column (Column 2) I showed above.

Comment: That still isn't a question...

Comment: So, the question is: how do I change the endpoints of my time interval so that at each row that has entry 0 in Column 1, I could get the correct time interval? See the expected output to be clearer.

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with the 2nd column stuff, despite all of my efforts spent above??

Comment: I don't know where `077891` came from. I think that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer. First, lets declare the array as `arr[MAX][8]`, that means you have `MAX` rows and `8` columns. This makes it easier to sort the data.

Next, lets create dummy data `0.100, 0.101, ...` that's easier to look at it.

To find the 5th column, you can use an additional loop (`for(int j = i; j < count; j++){...}`) to find the next non-zero value.

We have to keep track of total dead counts (`dead_count`) and increment each time `arr[i][1]` is zero.

[Kaplan-Meier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator) formula is taken as `1 - (double)dead_count/(double)count`

MCVE would look like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_2d_array(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    double a = *(double*)pa;
    double b = *(double*)pb;
    if(a > b) return 1;
    if(a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double arr[][8] =
    {
        { 0.100, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0 }, //initialize columns
        { 0.101, 1 }, // we can skip adding the zeros, it's done automatically
        { 0.102, 1 },
        { 0.103, 0 },
        { 0.104, 1 },
        { 0.105, 1 },
        { 0.106, 1 },
        { 0.107, 1 },
        { 0.108, 0 },
        { 0.109, 1 },
        { 0.110, 1 },
        { 0.111, 1 },
        { 0.112, 1 },
        { 0.113, 1 },
        { 0.114, 1 },
        { 0.115, 0 },
        { 0.116, 0 },
        { 0.117, 1 },
    };

    int count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);

    //sort
    qsort(arr, count, sizeof(arr[0]), compare_2d_array);

    int dead_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        double start = i ? arr[i - 1][0] : 0;
        double end = arr[i][0]; //<- I don't know what to use as default value!

        //if arr[i][1] is zero, then end should equal the next non-zero value
        double end;
        for(int j = i; j < count; j++)
        {
            end = arr[j][0];
            if(arr[j][1])
                break;
        }

        arr[i][2] = start;
        arr[i][3] = end;
        arr[i][4] = arr[i][1];
        arr[i][5] = !arr[i][1];

        if(!arr[i][1])
            dead_count++;

        printf("%3d %.6lf %.0lf [%.6lf %.6lf) %.0lf %.0lf %3d %.6lf\n", 
            i, 
            arr[i][0], 
            arr[i][1], 
            start,
            end, 
            arr[i][4], 
            arr[i][5], 
            count - i, 1 - (double)dead_count/(double)count );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  0 0.100000 1 [0.000000 0.100000) 1 0  18 1.000000
  1 0.101000 1 [0.100000 0.101000) 1 0  17 1.000000
  2 0.102000 1 [0.101000 0.102000) 1 0  16 1.000000
  3 0.103000 0 [0.102000 0.104000) 0 1  15 0.944444
  4 0.104000 1 [0.103000 0.104000) 1 0  14 0.944444
  5 0.105000 1 [0.104000 0.105000) 1 0  13 0.944444
  6 0.106000 1 [0.105000 0.106000) 1 0  12 0.944444
  7 0.107000 1 [0.106000 0.107000) 1 0  11 0.944444
  8 0.108000 0 [0.107000 0.109000) 0 1  10 0.888889
  9 0.109000 1 [0.108000 0.109000) 1 0   9 0.888889
 10 0.110000 1 [0.109000 0.110000) 1 0   8 0.888889
 11 0.111000 1 [0.110000 0.111000) 1 0   7 0.888889
 12 0.112000 1 [0.111000 0.112000) 1 0   6 0.888889
 13 0.113000 1 [0.112000 0.113000) 1 0   5 0.888889
 14 0.114000 1 [0.113000 0.114000) 1 0   4 0.888889
 15 0.115000 0 [0.114000 0.117000) 0 1   3 0.833333
 16 0.116000 0 [0.115000 0.117000) 0 1   2 0.777778
 17 0.117000 1 [0.116000 0.117000) 1 0   1 0.777778
```

Comment: Thanks @chucks, fixed

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried modifying my code above using your idea, and it works perfectly now!! Now, I have two follow-up questions:

1. I would like to store a series of values into an array at thousand discrete points (not necessarily integer), using column 7 in your output (it was not computed correctly) as the y-value and hopefully, column 2 as the x-input (so, for any given t, if t belongs t the interval [0.100 0.102), y[t] = 1.000000). I am thinking of doing a Nested-for Loops, but the index of an array must be integer, so how do we construct this *continuous* function y(t)?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. That has more to do with math than programming. I think you could make a linear estimation for `y(t)` based on `1/(dead_count - count)` - Let's say there are 4 death every second, then you get `popuplation - time * (death/second)`! - The other formula you were using was the so-called Greenwood's formula for variance (Wikipedia reference), I didn't understand how to calculate the variance.

Comment: No I did not mean to ask you a math question. I am sure the output I showed you above is the correct estimator. And you are right on the Greenwood's formula for variance as well. I was able to find another way to work around the question I just asked in the original comment, but now I have another one: I want to save all the outputs from `printf()` into a text file (for plotting purposes), so I tried putting `freopen ("myoutput.txt","w",stdout)` right in front of every lines that has `printf()`. The result is myoutput.txt file only has 2 outputs, compared to 1000 without adding `freopen()`.

Comment: Do you know why `freopen ("myoutput.txt","w",stdout)` fails to work here??

Comment: Call `freopen("myoutput.txt","w",stdout)` only once at the start. Otherwise it will overwrite the old data.